# How to quit VLC after playing a mp3 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, vlc

I have this function and I need to close the file before exiting the function say("some text").

```
def say(self, text):
    tts = gTTS(text, lang='fr')
    file="text.mp3"
    tts.save(file)
    audio = MP3(file)
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(file)
    p.play()
    time.sleep((audio.info.length)) #to avoid it listening to itself
    p.stop()
    return file
```

Because If I don't do this, I have this error

> OS Error: [Errno -9993] Illegal combination of I/O device

I think that this error occurs because I'm trying to listen just after the call of the function say and the file is still open.

nb: I'm working with Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though i am not to experienced with TTS, shouldnt it work if you just do `close(os.getcwd()+'/'+file)`?